# Use TypeORM repository or method on a service from outside any module

Tags: nestjs

I have a nestjs app that has an `AuthService` which has these parts:

```
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private readonly userRepo: Repository<User>,
    ) {}

async updateFromInternally () {
...
}
```

I have another file which is, crucially, *outside of any module*, which contains a number of helpful functions relating to Google oauth. For example, this file initiates Google's oauth2 client like so:

```
export const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT
);
```

This file also has a listener function which I found in Google's documentation as a way to catch when my use of Google's oauth2 client automatically uses a refresh token to obtain a new access token:

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', async (tokens) => {
    [****]
})
```

At [****], I need to query in my database for a particular user and update them. Either of these conceptually work:

1. I somehow get `userRepo` into this file right here and use it to query + update
2. I somehow call `updateFromInternally` in `AuthService` from here

But I don't know how to interact with either TypeORM repositories or methods within services from outside of any module in nestjs! Can I do either of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out #1:

```
import {getRepository} from "typeorm";

oauth2Client.on('tokens', async (tokens) => {
    const gaRepo = getRepository(Googleauth);
    // Can now use gaRepo like you do in a service
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The first question is why you're using `nestjs`?
You can access the internals of `nestjs` by using the instantiated `app`;

In your `main.ts` file you have something like this:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
```

You can access the services or `DataSource` from the app by using the `get` method.

```js
import {DataSource} from 'typeorm'

const dataSource = app.get<DataSource>(DataSource)
// or custom service
const someServices = app.get<SomeService>(SomeService)
```

you just need a way to export app from `main.ts` and import it in your outside world.

for example:

```js
// main.ts
let app;
async bootstrap() {
  app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
}

export const getApp = () => app;

bootstrap()
```

and in your other file

```js
// outside.ts
import {getApp} from './main.ts'

const app = getApp()
```

I didn't write the whole logic, but I think it would give you an idea of what you need to do.

But in my opinion, it's the worst thing you can do. You're using 'nestjs` and try to respect its philosophy.

Just write a module that handles all the work you want.